cut() in R does not work: "x" must be numeric, but it is
I have a table with timestamp and 9 columns filled with Numbers. Default, they were characters so I used:
library(dplyr)

data[-1] <- data[-1] %>% mutate_all(~as.numeric(as.character(.)))

Which worked just fine without any error. Now i want to group them and turn each value into "-", "o", "+" but it doesn't work, somehow...
for(j in 2:10) data[,j] <- cut(data[,j], c(-4,-0.5,0.5,4), labels= c("-","o","+"))
The error that appears (I translated myself, original in german)
"Fehler in cut.default(aggr_beer1[, j], c(-4, -0.5, 0.5, 4), labels = c("-",  :
'x' muss numerisch sein"
"Error in cut.default(aggr_beer1[, j], c(-4, -0.5, 0.5, 4), labels = c("-",  :
'x' must be numeric"
Can someone please help me? What am I doint wrong?

Notice the difference between
library(dplyr)

data[,2]
# A tibble: 5 × 1
      a
  <dbl>
1    -3
2    -2
3    -1
4     0
5     1

and
as.data.frame(data)[,2]
[1] -3 -2 -1  0  1

Subsetting a tibble by column (data[,X]) returns a tibble but cut needs a numeric vector. A data.frame drops the data frame structure when subsetting by only one column. As a side note, to keep the data frame use drop=F, e.g. as.data.frame(data)[,2,drop=F]
Another way to approach this, if this is your data
data <- structure(list(grp = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), a = c("-3", 
"-2", "-1", "0", "1"), b = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  grp   a     b    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     -3    2    
2 B     -2    3    
3 C     -1    4    
4 D     0     5    
5 E     1     6

Get the desired result with across
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(a:b, ~ 
           cut(as.numeric(.x), c(-4,-0.5,0.5,4), labels= c("-","o","+"))))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  grp   a     b    
  <chr> <fct> <fct>
1 A     -     +    
2 B     -     +    
3 C     -     +    
4 D     o     NA   
5 E     +     NA 

Note that mutate_all has been superseded by across, see ?mutate_all.
Use for(j in 2:3) data[,j] <- cut(data[,j,drop=T], c(-4,-0.5,0.5,4), labels= c("-","o","+")) to get your approach working.

For me, data[, 2] gives a vector, though.

because Andre is using a tibble and not a data.frame. if you run data[,2,drop=FALSE] you would get the same result. tibbles have drop=FALSE as default

@jay.sf Check if its a tibble. If I do data[,2] on the given tibble I get # A tibble: 5 × 1

I meant your data <- structure.

@jay.sf This is the good thing about tibbles, they work even if you haven't loaded dplyr. To get the tibble load library(dplyr) first.

I added library(dplyr) (which also loads tibble) to make the behavior more obvious.

I'd say they work inconsistently, regardless thanks for explanation.
